# Como saber cual palabra de una cadena es mas larga?

Tags: javascript, array, string

He intentado múltiples opciones pero todas me tiran incorrecto, si me pueden dar una ayuda con esta solución se los agradezco

**Requerimiento:**
La funcion llamada 'palabraMasLarga' recive un array 'array' de frases (strings) como parametro
y debe devolver la palabra mas larga entre todas las frases ( Es decir la palabra con mayor cantidad de caracteres)
Por ej:
palabraMasLarga(['hola esto string', 'frase con palabra']) debe devolver 'palabra'

```javascript
function palabraMasLarga(array) {
   var words = array.split(" ")
   var myLongestWord = ""
   for(let word in words) {
      if(word.length > ) {
         myLongestWord = word;
      }
   }
   return myLongestWord
}
```

Comment: Lo primero que debes hacer, es [editar tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/554004/edit) y **poner el código a TEXTO**. quien quiera ayudarte, tiene que tomarse la molestia de teclear la imagen completa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacer algo así:

```
  function palabraMasLarga(listaFrases) {
    const todasLasPalabras = listaFrases
      .join(" ") // Devuelve un String con todas las palabras
      .split(" "); // Devuelve un array con todas las palbras

    let result = ""; // Variable auxiliar para guardar la palabra más grande

    //Recorre todas las palabras y guarda en result la palabra recorrida
    //si esta es mas larga que la ultima agregada en result.
    for (palabra of todasLasPalabras) {
      if (palabra.length > result.length) result = palabra;
    }
    return result; //retorna la palabra mas larga obtenida
  }

  palabraMasLarga(["hola esto string", "frase con palabra"]);
  //Devuelve "palabra"
```

**.join(" ")**

Convierte esto: ["hola esto string", "frase con palabra"]

En esto: "hola esto string frase con palabra"

**.split(" ")**

Convierte esto: "hola esto string frase con palabra"

En esto: ["hola","esto","string","frase","con","palabra"]

Luego este último array obtenido se recorre y se verifica si el largo de la palabra es mayor al largo de result, en la primer iteración el largo de result es 0 ya que es un string vacío, por lo que result pasa a ser la primer palabra.
Luego en cada iteración verifica si la palabra recorrida es más larga que la que está en result, si eso se cumple result pasa a ser igual a esa palabra.
Finalmente retorna result.

Link a documentación join:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Link a documentación split: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Así quedaría sin comentarios:

```
  function palabraMasLarga(listaFrases) {
    const todasLasPalabras = listaFrases
      .join(" ")
      .split(" ");

    let result = "";    

    for (palabra of todasLasPalabras) {
      if (palabra.length > result.length) result = palabra;
    }
    return result;
  }

  palabraMasLarga(["hola esto string", "frase con palabra"]);
  //Devuelve "palabra"
```

Answer (score 0):

Te faltó dividir el array de arrays primero:

```
function palabraMasLarga(array){
    var myLongestWord = "";
    array.forEach(function (item){
        item.split(" ").forEach(function (word){
            if(word.length > myLongestWord.length) {
                myLongestWord = word;
            }
        });
    });
    return myLongestWord;
}
    
palabraMasLarga(['hola esto string', 'frase con palabra']);
```